# Kotlin Multiplatform build OUTPUT_SIZE error

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm having this error happen to me, out of the blue and have no ideia where it came from and why it happened. It' breaking on GitHub CI with the same error message. Any clue about what's  happening?

**gradle-wrapper:**
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip`

**Error message:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: OUTPUT_SIZE
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.execute(Tasks.kt:365)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4227.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    ...
```

My `settings.gradlew.kts` file:

```
enableFeaturePreview("VERSION_CATALOGS")
enableFeaturePreview("TYPESAFE_PROJECT_ACCESSORS")

pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }

    plugins {
        kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.6.20"
        id("org.jetbrains.compose") version "1.1.1"
    }
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Module `build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("plugin.serialization")
}

kotlin {
    jvm {
           compilations.all {
              kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"
           }
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(libs.kotlinx.serialization)
            }
        }

        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(libs.bundles.tests)
            }
        }

        val jvmMain by getting
        val jvmTest by getting
    }
}
```

Comment: try creating a new project and replicating the problem there. If you can't compare your gradle setup with this new project, and move parts by parts. If this didn't helped you to solve the problem by yourself, create a minimal reproducible project which can be shared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be happening when trying to run compose version 1.1.1 with kotlin 1.6.20. Downgrading kotlin version or updating compose version seemed to fix the problem.

Comment: I'm getting this error with Compose (desktop) 1.1.0 and Kotlin 1.6.10, which should be compatible according to [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin)